# Detection of dominant bit during Intermission on CAN bus

Tags: can-bus, canoe

Hi i just start reading CAN protocol and i just stuck here with these.

On CAN bus overload frame comes only with 2 conditions

1. when internally receiver is not good enough to take next frame
2. when dominant bit detected during INTERMISSION.
   SO at what scenario second condition can happen ?
   what are other effects of this scenario on CAN bus as well as others nodes?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

INTERMISSION period means during the transmission of INTER FRAME SPACE (Three recessive bits) in between DATA and REMOTE frame.During INTERMISSION period the bus is in IDLE state and none of the node is not permitted to initiates the transmission.During intermission period any dominant bit is detected in between data and remote frame (due to noise),a OVERLOAD FRAME is generated.
       The Bus idle state is lasts until a node has something to transmits at which detection of a dominant bit on the bus at SOF.